# How to make a swipe strobe..?

Tags: android, user-interface, view, android-custom-view

[image]

I was going through application I just downloaded (Super-Bright LED Flashlight)(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.surpax.ledflashlight.panel&hl=en) and I am interested in implement strobe in my application the same way it is there in app but have no idea on from where to start. Please help.

Comment: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/sliders.html# and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html

Comment: The strobe in this application is kind of rotatory.

Comment: Not necessarily. Possibly, it's only sliding. In the given image there's a slight illusion of curvature. But It seems to be something flat with some clever shadows overlayed.

Answer (score 3):

You may follow the [Wheel](https://github.com/sephiroth74/AndroidWheel) View library in github:

Use it like this:

```
<it.sephiroth.android.wheel.view.Wheel
            android:id="@+id/wheel"
            xmlns:sephiroth="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            sephiroth:numRotations="6"
            sephiroth:ticks="28" />
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: No problem! Glad I help. Remember to mark my answer as correct so everyone can find this library in searches if needed.